# SD card does not appear as adoptable

Tags: adb, sd-card, adoptable-storage

I have a Samsung Galaxy On5 that has been rooted, and I want to adopt my SD card as internal storage. I am attempting to adopt the SD card using ADB. The process for this is well documented, but every guide I have found assumes that the SD card is listed following the command `sm list-disks adoptable`. My SD card is listed after using the command `sm list-disks`, but not after using `sm list-disks adoptable`. The card has been freshly formatted, and contains no data. Is there any reason why my sd card might not be adoptable?

Comment: Scream "You are going to be adopted!" To it :) in all seriousness, what format is the SD in? It may be an issue there.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think the format is some variant of FAT, likely FAT32 or exFAT. The research that I've done since asking indicates that it might need to be in ext2, ext3, or ext4. Is this correct?

Comment: I believe so. You may need a Linux computer to get that format though :)

Comment: I have formatted the entire SD card to ext4, but I still get the same results from the ADB commands - appears in `sm list-disks` but not `sm list-disks adoptable` . Would one of the other two ext formats work better? Is there another factor other than format which might prevent my phone from adopting the drive?

Comment: Size, possibly. How big is the SD compared to your phone storage??

Comment: Phone storage is 8GB, SD card is 16GB.

Comment: Hmmph. No idea. Hang on... Does your device even support this?

Comment: Without rooting, you can't adopt storage on a Samsung phone. I have, however, seen reports form other On5 users that they have successfully force-adopted SD cards on their rooted phones.

Comment: @Draconic False, you don't need root to setup adoptable storage

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје, that depends on the phone. Some phones allow adoptable storage by default, but some manufacturers do not allow their phones to set up adoptable storage short of tampering with the phone via root. My phone is one of the latter category.